# Is it possible to make a redirection issuing POST verb in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect to an action method of another controller such that the browser issues POST instead of GET verb.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the nature of a "redirect" in HTTP terms is an instruction to the browser to perform a HTTP GET to a particular URL.

So, in HTTP terms - it's not possible.

**However** :)

Instead of doing `RedirectToAction("ActionMethod", "Controller", new { param = value })`, you could do `return View("ActionMethod", value)` which would pass the `value` as a key/value pair in the HTTP POST body, assuming `ActionMethod` is setup with `[HttpPost]`, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionMethod(string param) 
{

}
```

However, keep in mind that will not perform a redirect - it's like of the equivalent of a cross-page postback in ASP.NET Web Forms.